# Role of 'p' Orbitals in Graphite Carbons

Tags: organic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, bond, hybridization, valence-bond-theory

In the graphite arrangement of carbons, if we model them according to hybridization theory, the carbons in graphite are sp2 hybridized. This would mean that one s and two p orbitals hybridize, making 3 hybridized orbitals. This clearly would make the molecular structure trigonal planar. However, 1 electron is left. Wouldn't this electron be found in the remaining p orbital that wasn't hybridize? I couldn't find any information about this so I ask it here. Moreover, if this is the case, would this p orbital of a carbon in a layer overlap with the other p orbitals in the top and bottom layers?

If I said something that is wrong, feel free to correct me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am nitpicking: Atoms cannot hybridize, only the mathematical representations of orbitals can. Hybridisation itself is not a theory but a description. Hybridisation always follows structure, not the other way around. Hence, the sheets in graphite are (in good approximation) planar, that's why the carbons can be well described with sp² orbitals.

Answer (score 2):

By the obsolete concept of hybridization, all carbon atoms in graphite are sp<sup>2</sup> hybridized. A total of three (1 - 2s and 2 p-orbitals) lead to this hybridization. Due to the formation of sigma bonds with axial overlap of one of these sp<sup>2</sup> orbitals with another sp<sup>2</sup> orbital of another centre, the atoms exist as a planar array of hexagonal carbon rings. The odd electron resides in the remaining unhybridized p-orbital of sp<sup>2</sup> carbon centre, perpendicular to the plane containing the three equivalent sp<sup>2</sup> hybrid orbitals. The last odd electron is not localized in the unhybridized p-orbital, but is rather delocalized throughout the layer, due to lateral pπ - pπ, overlap, causing conjugation of odd electron, throughout the plane. It is a bit like an ethylene molecule with H-C bonds replaced by C-C bonds over an enormous plane.

(This is a reason for the high electric conductivity of graphite compared to other carbon allotrophs and other non metals).

[image: Image courtesy: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Structure-of-graphite_fig6_283081312]

Unhybridized p-orbitals (of C atoms in adjacent planes) do not overlap end to end.

In this diagram, the distance between the two adjacent layers of graphite ~0.34 nm (order of 10<sup>-9</sup>) >>>>>>> greater than the longitudinal length of a lobe of the perpendicular p-orbital projecting from a plane - in the order of picometers (order of 10<sup>-12</sup>), so clearly they are not large enough to overcome the immense distance of seperation to overlap.

Moreover, the odd electrons in them are already in conjugation, by pπ - pπ lateral overlap. This will further retard any cross-layer bonding interaction.

Comment: This could end with "indeed graphite is a lubricant as for the planes can slide on each others". Plus 1, it seems useful to OP.

Comment: I am downvoting this after I read the first sentence. Hybridisation is not an obsolete concept. It is still a widely used and successful (approximate) mathematical description. In a way it is part of the foundations for (quantitative and qualitative) Valence Bond theory. Also - still the first sentence - atoms cannot be hybridised, so an sp² hybridised carbon simply does not exist. If you are going to reject hybridisation, which I can understand, please get the terminology right.

Comment: I am also going to object to that order of magnitude comparison. If a bond is 140 pm according to your graphic, and the distance between the sheets is 340 pm, then that is not three orders of magnitude, it is only triple (or a third). There certainly are orbital interactions between the sheets, that is just the nature of the mathematics behind it.